# I believe my question has a concrete, specific answer, but it was closed as Not Constructive

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-constructive

I asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/14541047/1888017 and for some reason it's closed. I can't figure out why. I read the FAQ several times, and I know that it is possible to make a concrete answer, because it's just about differences between protocols and their performance.

And it's also not broad, like how to build a rocket or a million-dollar business.

So please explain to me what's wrong with it.

Comment: I think -5 is a very high rate for such a bad and nonconstructive question. Better will be making it -50

Comment: Patience, it will get there.

Answer (score 8):

It's impossibly broad. A person could write a book attempting to give a comprehensive answer to the several questions you pose. The FAQ specifically states that 'it would take a book' is too broad.

Comment: And added to that, they seem to be research questions answerable by the OP. Learn what those protocols are by doing some homework and you'll figure out most of the answers too.

Comment: That's funny. I think that short description of each protocol possible to make in 3-4 rows. There are 4 protocols. that's mean 16 rows. And link to benchmark. Not looks like a book. Ah, and also there a lot of question with such structure on stackoverflow and they are opened and people successfully answering on them...

Comment: @Ph0en1x That doesn't mean the question is a good fit for SO, it means it was asked and people attempted to answer. If the answer you're looking for is so generic, *then* it doesn't fit for a different reason--no research effort.

Comment: We specifically don't do 'list' questions here. The answers are instantly out of date and can't be maintained. I also question the premise that such a quickie-list would be useful. If you think it would, create it and put it on your blog.

Comment: That's the perfect choice, but for some stupid reason 2 million of software developer do not read my blog.

Answer (score 7):

There's no concrete, specific answer with the information you provided. (Even with specifics, I find it unlikely there would be an answer that's "concrete and specific" in a meaningful way.)

Why are there so many protocols? Why are there so many sodas? Beers? Sausages? Each one has something going for it. Each one scratches a particular itch. And sausage is delicious.

What specific features do each provide? This is documented in each implementation's docs.

Do they have differences in performance? Of course they do. *What* those differences are, and where or not they *matter* in your case, depend on your case, and we have zero information about that.

The documentation of each, and performance testing under your specific usecase, will be the specific, concrete answer you seek.

Comment: Are sausages delicious for scratching itches? I am confused. `;)`

Answer (score 4):

It's enormously wide. It's a great example of a question that could be answered by a book. Consider asking which is supported by more platforms/libraries/programming languages (pick ONE) or which is fastest for a particular kind of use (be detailed) or which is easiest to learn, or easiest to hire developers who already know, or easiest to debug, or capable of handling your particular payload (large, or oddly formatted, or whatever) or most secure, or ....

ONE question. Not "tell me about the differences". It would be like asking whether I should live in Canada or Europe. Unanswerable in general, and you've provided no details to take it away from the general.

Comment: Canada. Europe! One of those two.

Comment: Canada or Europe! That is the answer, when it is not 42.